# Can I reassign an exception type in catch block and rethrow it?

Tags: java, exception

It seems that the compiler considers `e` as an `Exception` even if I reassign it to a `RuntimeException`

```
try{
     throw new RuntimeException();
}catch (Exception e){
  e = new RuntimeException();
  throw e; // Compiler Error here: Unhandled exception: java.lang.Exception
}
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: `throw new RuntimeException(e);`

Comment: Don't reassign exceptions but wrap them like Sotirios showed. Otherwise you'd loose valuable information, e.g. the type of the original exception and the source of that exception (stack trace).

Comment: And why does the compiler complain about `throw e`? Because it only sees `Exception e` no matter what you assigned. It's much like `Object o = new String("whatever");` - the compiler only knows that `o` has the type `Object`.